# How can I do a curtain effect on a web like showed in the image?

Tags: web, background, 2d, effect

[curtain effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS21v.gif)

Hello I need to make this effect in a photo viewer, I have no idea how to make it, please any help?

Comment: Looking at the curtain effect hyperlink I cannot tell, but it looks like you may be in a web browser?

Comment: I see you added a tag 'Web' to the original question.  Does this mean you are attempting to create a web application and need help on a web app?  You are allowed to add comments, or edit the original question as needed.

Comment: Yes, you're right that's what I am looking for, do you know if I can use css o jquery?

Comment: Yes, i can see how CSS and javascript could be used.  It seems to me there are two layers.  The bottom layer has the black and white image.  the top layer has color describing what appears to be radar mapping of cloud density.  The mouse pointer could cause the top layer to clip revealing the bottom layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume there are two layers, top layer has color, bottom layer has greyscale we can achieve the desired results.  Here is an example using a single HTML file and two image files.  The image files are identical except one is color, the other is greyscale.  We use CSS for position of the elements and z-index order, and use jquery for mouse event handling to reduce the size of the top layer giving a clipping effect.  The only other piece I can tell is changing the mouse pointer to some arbitrary horizontal rule, and vertical rule to give a curtain effect...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        .picture-container 
        {
            position: absolute;
        }

        #picture-container-color
        {
            z-index:2;
            background-image: url("flower-color.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: red;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        #picture-container-grey
        {
            z-index:1;
            background-image: url("flower-grey.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="picture-container-color" class="picture-container"></div>
    <div id="picture-container-grey" class="picture-container"></div>

    <script>
        var mousedown = false;

        $(".picture-container").mousedown(function(event) {
            mousedown = true;
        });

        $(".picture-container").mousemove(function(event) {
            if (mousedown === true) {
                $("#picture-container-color").width(event.pageX);
                $("#picture-container-color").height(event.pageY);
            }
        });

        $(".picture-container").mouseup(function(event) {
            mousedown = false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```